# Python - Sistema de inventario

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu estou fazendo um mini jogo de exemplo para poder aprender mais sobre python, e eu não sei como faço para remover o `self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 200, 290, 80, tag='inventario', fill='yellow')`
(INVENTARIO ATIVADO), vou dar um exemplo… Quando eu pressiono a tecla i ele cria um rectangle que seria um inventário, mas para abrir é fácil, eu gostaria de saber como faço para esconder, ou ''fechar'', ou inventario quando eu apertar i Novamente

Esse é o meu código

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('Sources\music.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
class janela:
    def __init__(self, janela):
        self.canvas = Canvas(janela,
                            takefocus=1, bg='black')
        janela.config(bg='red')
        janela.title('Mini jogo de bosta')

        self.canvas.bind('a', self.esquerda)
        self.canvas.bind('A', self.esquerda)
        self.canvas.bind('<Left>', self.esquerda)

        self.canvas.bind('d', self.direita)
        self.canvas.bind('D', self.direita)
        self.canvas.bind('<Right>', self.direita)

        self.canvas.bind('w', self.cima)
        self.canvas.bind('W', self.cima)
        self.canvas.bind('<Up>', self.cima)

        self.canvas.bind('s', self.baixo)
        self.canvas.bind('S', self.baixo)
        self.canvas.bind('<Down>', self.baixo)

        #Bind Inventory

        self.canvas.bind('I', self.inventario)
        self.canvas.bind('i', self.inventario)

        self.canvas.focus_force()
        self.canvas.pack()

        #Person
        #X1, Y1, X2, Y2
        self.canvas.create_oval(90, 90, 110, 110,
                                tag='Player', fill='Green')
        self.canvas.create_oval(95, 104, 105, 124, 
                                tag='Player', fill='Green')
        self.canvas.create_oval(100, 119, 105, 129,
                                tag='Player', fill='Green')
        self.canvas.create_oval(93, 119, 98, 129,
                                tag='Player', fill='Green')
                                
        self.canvas.create_oval(102, 100, 107, 95, 
                                tag='Player', fill='black')
        self.canvas.create_oval(93, 100, 98, 95,
                                tag='Player', fill='black')
            
    def esquerda(self, event): self.canvas.move('Player', -10, 0)
    def direita(self, event): self.canvas.move('Player', 10, 0)
    def cima(self, event): self.canvas.move('Player', 0, -10)
    def baixo(self, event): self.canvas.move('Player', 0, 10)

    #ação inventario

    def inventario(self, event):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 200, 290, 80,
                                    tag='inventario', fill='yellow')
        print('inventario aberto')
        
        
jan1 = Tk()
janela(jan1)
jan1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como resolver da forma proposta no entanto o pygame dispõe de controle indicados:

```
for events in pygame.event.get():# sair
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("faça algo")
            if events.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:# move
                if events.key == pygame.K_w:
                    print("faça algo")
                if events.key == pygame.K_s:#move
                    print("faça algo")
            if events.type == pygame.KEYUP:#move
                if events.key == pygame.K_w:
                    print("faça algo")
                if events.key == pygame.K_s:#move
                    print("faça algo")
```

Comment: Eu vou tentar ser mais específico no problema

Quando eu aperto i cria um retângulo amarelo, como posso fazer com que o retângulo suma quando eu pressionar i novamente?

Answer (score -1):

Porque nao tenta condicionar a abertura ao valor de uma variavel?

Crie uma variável com valor zero, e ao pressionar i essa variável recebe um valor 1. Porem ao pressionar o i novamente, essa variável recebe + 1.
E aí a condição para essa se passar de 1, se torna zero resetando tudo!

Eresumindo: O "inventario"? Depende dessa variável com valor 1 e essa se passa de um se torna 0.
Eu tento programar no game maker e la eu faria algo assim:

```
//Criando a variável 
Var inv=0

//step, read sei lá...
If keypress =i
    {inv +=1}

If inv ==1
     {Seu code de inventário}

If inv >=2 inv=0// reseta a var
```

Basicamente é isto.
Faça suas adaptações talvez funcione. Boa sorte

Eu so conheci o pythom agora e estou muito animado com a linguagem e vou praticar, mas o gml e praticamente a mesma coisa com leves modificações.